# When merging/diffing with subversion, can someone explain the difference between --ignore-space-change (-b) and --ignore-all-space (-w)?

Tags: svn, merge

Could someone give me an explanation for these two switches? Are they mutually exclusive? Or -w includes -b?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider 3 lines:

```
1: "ab"
2: "a b"
3: "a  b"
```

With `-w`, all three lines compare the same.
With `-b`, 2 and 3 compare the same but 1 is considered different.

If you use `-w` then `-b` is irrelevant.

Comment: Great and succinct explanation Brian. Thanks!